# Show images in grid view whose network path stored in database

Tags: asp.net

I have images saved in a network location and their paths are saved in a database. 
The issue is when I retrieve the image path from the database the path looks like:

```
  \\\\dev1\\mr_item_images\\8 port planet switch.Jpeg.
```

while the actual path saved in the database is

```
  \\dev1\mr_item_images\8 port planet switch.Jpeg.
```

Due to this the image is not showing the grid view that  map the image to.

Comment: i think path should be stored with "/" instead of "\"

Answer (score 0):

May this help you:

Here Mudassar Ahmed Khan has explained with an example and attached sample code

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-images-using-a-file-path-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet.aspx